# How to implement Select Type in OroPlatform?

Tags: symfony, orocommerce

I would like to extend the customer user entity and add a field of type "Select".

I'm not able to find an example in documentation nor source code of Oro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a documentation on how to create select type fields using schema migrations:
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities/extend-entities/enums/